# QString argument templates not understood

Tags: c++, templates, qstring

I have a QString template with static numbers, mixed in with argument/template placeholders like %1 and %2.  For example:

```
QString("123%1%26789").arg("4").arg("5")
```

The %1 should be replaced with 4, and %2 should be replaced with 5.  But the second placeholder confuses C++/Qt because the placeholder can't separate the %2 from the neighboring 6.

I tried %{2} and other silly things, but no luck.  Is there a ways to achieve this without create two statements, appending the remainder of the string in the second statement:

```
QString("123%1%2").arg("4").arg("5")+QString("6789")
```

The results should be:

```
123456789
```

Comment: Managed to reproduce (with Qt5.15.2).  Replacing `%2` with `%02` appears to 'fix' the problem.

Comment: Explanatory note for readers:  The QString doc page says that "Place marker numbers must be in the range 1 to 99"... hence the arg() method is expanding `%26` instead of the expanding `%2` followed by a literal 6.

Answer (score -1):

QString("123%1%%2%789").arg("4").arg("6")

Here, the first placeholder (%1) will be replaced with "4", and the second placeholder (%2) will be replaced with "6". The %% in between them will be interpreted as a literal percent sign and will not be replaced.

This will result in a QString "1234%6789", which has the desired replacements.

Comment: I don't what the % in the final string...that's the problem.  Without that third % the %2 is interpreted as %2789